# Detailed monitoring of AWS Workspaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-workspaces

We have multiple Windows based workspaces deployed for client. We have used WSP protocol for this & the servers are Windows 2016 or 2019 one. We had many complaints from client side that the workspace was slow or facing some net issues. We have provisioned ample disk space for them & compute used is PowerPro type.

Is there any way for us to monitor CPU, Ram & network performance of workspaces? The AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/cloudwatch-metrics.html) do not specify this. Let me know if we some inbuit services that we can leverage or any third party service is required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try using AWS CloudWatch to monitor your workspaces. You can monitor every metric you've asked for with CloudWatch and it's already integrated with AWS Workspaces. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi!The basic dashboard for workspace comes with details having user connected or not, healthy/ unhealthy, etc.
Or do you mean to say to manually install unified cloudwatch agent to get detailed metrics? If so, does unified cloudwatch agent support installation on workspace as it comes under managed instances?

Answer (score 0):

eG Innovations provides a good solution for monitoring AWS WorkSpaces. See https://www.eginnovations.com/supported-technologies/aws-workspaces-monitoring

Don't think AWS CloudWatch gives ready made metrics/dashboards/reports like this.